# share link from a link of a web page

Tags: android, html, ios

I have to add one button on my web page which if i click on my phone should redirect to app OR if i open in my desktop it should open in browser.

Code/link which i am creating for my web page looks like this:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:50px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                      Get Started
                      </a>
```

It would be great if it works for both Android and iOS.

Comment: This is from app changes, i want to change my html web page to do ...

Comment: You don't need to change website, you need to make receive the link only.

Comment: Okay, I will try that